# Android:how to load image from excel to android

Tags: android

**Excel to Android:**

Here I want to load image from excel cell to android application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you're writing the application in Java you can use this wonderful library by Apache : [Apache POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) which allows you to read Excel files and access their parts as convenient objects. You can request all images from a workbook and iterate access them as files, for instance:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(anExcelFile));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();
for (Iterator it = lst.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();
    String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();
    byte[] data = pict.getData();
    if (ext.equals("jpeg")){
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict.jpg");
      out.write(data);
      out.close();
    }
}
```

you can also get access to individual sheets, rows, etc. have a look at their documentation.